# Find $1/\alpha$ when basis is {1, $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, $\alpha^3$}

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate a sub field and in the process, I need to state $1/\alpha$ in terms of $\alpha$.

Now, my $\alpha$ = $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{20}}$.

I can't for the life of me do this simple calculation!!

The minimal polynomial is $x^4-6x^2-11$ and I know I should be able to state $1/\alpha$ in terms of 1, $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3$ but it is just not working for me.

Can someone please explain to me how to get the solution??

Comment: Hint: $(1/\alpha)(\alpha^4-6\alpha^2-11)=\alpha^3-6\alpha-11/\alpha$.

Comment: Multiplicatively invert. Lift the square-root to the whole expression. Multiply by the square root of the conjugate of the expression under the squareroot. Take the squareroots outside into one squareroot.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\alpha^4-6\alpha^2=11$. Divide on both sides by $11\alpha$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you - I knew it was something simple but I just couldn't work it out today!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just rewrite the minimal equation as
$$\alpha^4-6\alpha^2=\alpha(\alpha^3-6\alpha)=11,$$
so $\quad\alpha^{-1}=\frac1{11}(\alpha^3-6\alpha)$.

Comment: Thank you - I knew it was something simple but I just couldn't work it out today!!!

Comment: It happens to all of us from time to time!